# Best way to parse JSON Response from Google Maps?

Tags: apex, json, rest

I've written something that will get the longitude and latitude from a Google Geocode Callout.

The response we get from a generic callout looks like this:

```
{  
   results=(   {  
      address_components=(      {  
         long_name=1600,
         short_name=1600,
         types=(street_number 
    )
      },
      {  
         long_name=Amphitheatre Parkway,
         short_name=Amphitheatre Pkwy,
         types=(route)
      },
      {  
         long_name=Mountain View,
         short_name=Mountain View,
         types=(locality,
         political)
      },
      {  
         long_name=Santa Clara County,
         short_name=Santa Clara County,
         types=(administrative_area_level_2,
         political)
      },
      {  
         long_name=California,
         short_name=CA,
         types=(administrative_area_level_1,
         political)
      },
      {  
         long_name=United States,
         short_name=US,
         types=(country,
         political)
      },
      {  
         long_name=94043,
         short_name=94043,
         types=(postal_code)
      }      ),
      formatted_address=1600 Amphitheatre Pkwy,
      Mountain View,
      CA 94043,
      USA,
      geometry=      {  
         location=         {  
            lat=37.4223582,
            lng=-122.0844464
         },
         location_type=ROOFTOP,
         viewport=         {  
            northeast=            {  
               lat=37.4237071802915,
               lng=-122.0830974197085
            },
            southwest=            {  
               lat=37.4210092197085,
               lng=-122.0857953802915
            }
         }
      },
      place_id=ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA,
      types=(street_address)
   }   ),
   status=OK
}
```

Specifically I'm interested in the following part:

```
  geometry=      {  
     location=         {  
        lat=37.4223582,
        lng=-122.0844464
     },
```

I've written a small HTTP class that parses through the response and puts the Longitude and Latitude into the `Double lng, lat;` variables that can then be processed into a Geolocation field.

```
Http http = new Http();
HttpRequest request = new HttpRequest();
request.setEndpoint('https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=1600+Amphitheatre+Parkway,+Mountain+View,+CA&key=[MY_API_KEY]');
request.setMethod('GET');

HttpResponse response = http.send(request);

Double lat, lng;

if (response.getStatusCode() == 200) {
    JSONParser parser = JSON.createParser(response.getBody());

    while (parser.nextToken() != null) {
        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME && parser.getText() == 'geometry') {
            while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {
                if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME && parser.getText() == 'location') {
                    while (parser.nextToken() != JSONToken.END_OBJECT) {



                        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME && parser.getText() == 'lat') {
                            parser.nextToken();
                            lat = Double.valueOf(parser.getText());
                        }

                        if (parser.getCurrentToken() == JSONToken.FIELD_NAME && parser.getText() == 'lng') {
                            parser.nextToken();
                            lng = Double.valueOf(parser.getText());
                        }

                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

System.debug('@@@@@ Lat: ' + lat);
System.debug('@@@@@ Lng: ' + lng);
```

Whilst this works, I'm not convinced I'm parsing it in the best way possible and that with so many `while` iterations and `if` statements that it couldn't be more efficient.

Is there a better way to parse through a JSON response, such as what Google provides from a Geocoder response?

Comment: Just use the heroku JSON2apex app and deserialize the response into an object. https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/

Comment: The response you have posted is not valid JSON.

Comment: @KeithC I did think that, but wasn't 100% sure has I ripped the response from the debug logs. Maybe I've done something wrong. It is interesting that the code above works, given that though. Unless debugging it strips things out?

Comment: Not sure why you are seeing that output. JSON is [this simple](http://json.org/), just pretty much  `{ } [ ] :` plus numbers and quoted strings.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not a parser! Just deserialize:

```
public class Response { final Geometry geometry; }
public class Geometry { final Location location; }
public class Location { final Decimal latitude, longitude; }
```

Granted, your JSON payload is not valid as currently specified. The above would work though if your structure boils down to:

```
{
    "geometry": {
        "location": {
            "latitude": 0.0,
            "longitude": 0.0
        }
    },
    "other_properties": { /*values*/ }
}
```

---

If you want to copy the payload format listed [here](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro), the class would be slightly different.

**JSON**

> ```
> {
>    "results" : [
>       {
>          "address_components" : [...],
>          "formatted_address" : "1600 Amphitheatre Parkway, Mountain View, CA 94043, USA",
>          "geometry" : {
>             "location" : {
>                "lat" : 37.4224764,
>                "lng" : -122.0842499
>             },
>             "location_type" : "ROOFTOP",
>             "viewport" : {
>                "northeast" : {
>                   "lat" : 37.4238253802915,
>                   "lng" : -122.0829009197085
>                },
>                "southwest" : {
>                   "lat" : 37.4211274197085,
>                   "lng" : -122.0855988802915
>                }
>             }
>          },
>          "place_id" : "ChIJ2eUgeAK6j4ARbn5u_wAGqWA",
>          "types" : [ "street_address" ]
>       }
>    ],
>    "status" : "OK"
> }
> ```

**Apex**

```
public class Response { final List<Result> results; }
public class Result { final Geometry geometry; }
public class Geometry { final Location location; }
public class Location { final Decimal latitude, longitude; }
```

Comment: Obligatory link: https://json2apex.herokuapp.com/.

Comment: Except that's going to give you a bunch of irrelevant structure you don't care about. It's not rocket surgery converting JSON structure to an `Apex Class` representation. When you just want to cherry pick a small portion of the structure, I personally would *avoid* using that tool.

Comment: Can you make your answer more complete? Based on https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/geocoding/intro there is an array to deal with too.

Comment: I'll give that a go. Thanks Adrian! And thanks @sfdcfox. I should've mentioned I was aware of that, but I'm intentionally trying to reinvent the wheel a bit. Purely so I understand "GET"  HTTP callouts a bit better (pun not initially intended, but now is).